# Reorder plot values below diagonal line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I have a data file organized by row with an x label, y label, and then a value. The basic structure looks like this:

`Factor_1,Factor_2,Number

apple,apple,1

banana,apple,1

apple,kiwi,6

apple,pear,1

watermelon,apple,8

banana,banana,3

banana,kiwi,2

banana,pear,1

banana,watermelon,9

kiwi,kiwi,9

pear,kiwi,4

kiwi,watermelon,4

pear,pear,3

pear,watermelon,9

watermelon,watermelon,1

...

...`

Using this data, I'm building something akin to a correlation matrix using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

d <- read.csv("my_file", head=TRUE, sep="\t")
x <- dcast(d, Factor_1~Factor_2)
x.m <- melt(x)
x.m <- ddply(x.m, .(variable))
(p <- ggplot(x.m, aes(variable, Factor_1)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "black") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "green")
```

The above code gives me a plot that looks like this:

[image: plot]

How can I reorder the data to build a plot with the following format where all the data is grouped below the diagonal line?

```
   A  B  K  P  W
W              1
P           3  9
K        9  4  4
B     3  2  1  9
A  1  1  6  1  8
```

Comment: When I run it, the code and data subset you've posted produce a plot that looks just like what you've requested. Have you tried running the posted example yourself? Also, there's a missing right parenthesis in the  final line of your code.

Comment: @DWin -- Second line of the first code block is `apple,apple,1` . Or did you mean something different?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien You're correct; the fruit example does, in fact, produce the desired output. In my actual data set the x and y labels are not in the proper order. I've updated the data set to depict my problem. Note that some rows (eg. `watermelon,apple,8`) are out of order.

Comment: @dr.bunsen Right you are. I'll post my approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I called it 'fruits':

```
fruit.tbl <- xtabs(V3 ~ V1+V2, data=fruits)
> melt(fruit.tbl)
           V1         V2 value
1       apple      apple     1
2      banana      apple     0
3        kiwi      apple     0
4        pear      apple     0
5  watermelon      apple     0
6       apple     banana     1
7      banana     banana     3
8        kiwi     banana     0
9        pear     banana     0
10 watermelon     banana     0
11      apple       kiwi     6
12     banana       kiwi     2
13       kiwi       kiwi     9
14       pear       kiwi     0
15 watermelon       kiwi     0
16      apple       pear     1
17     banana       pear     1
18       kiwi       pear     4
19       pear       pear     3
20 watermelon       pear     0
21      apple watermelon     8
22     banana watermelon     9
23       kiwi watermelon     4
24       pear watermelon     9
25 watermelon watermelon     1

mfruit <- melt(fruit.tbl)
is.na(mfruit$value) <- mfruit$value==0

# Needed to swap x and y to get it the way you wanted
 (p <- ggplot(melt(mfruit), aes(V2, V1,fill = value)) + 
                geom_tile( colour = "black") + 
                scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "green")
   )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to right away get the elements in the first two columns of your data.frame in the proper order. (One note: for this to work, both columns should be of class **character**. If the are instead factors, coerce them first with `as.character()`.)

After doing the following, the plot should come out just as you'd like it:

```
ordered <- apply(d[c("Factor_1", "Factor_2")], 1, sort)
d[c("Factor_1")] <- ordered[1,]
d[c("Factor_2")] <- ordered[2,]
```

To see what that code did, here are the first 6 rows of the data.frame before reordering:

```
    Factor_1 Factor_2 Number
1      apple    apple      1
2     banana    apple      1
3      apple     kiwi      6
4      apple     pear      1
5 watermelon    apple      8
6     banana   banana      3
```

and here they are afterwards:

```
  Factor_1   Factor_2 Number
1    apple      apple      1
2    apple     banana      1
3    apple       kiwi      6
4    apple       pear      1
5    apple watermelon      8
6   banana     banana      3
```